# onPressed code not working as expected in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm having a problem with my continue button.

The logic for my continue button is: If the user's email is verified then he should be taken to the home page of my app(I'm building a password manager, so my home page is the password view) but if he's email is not verified then he should remain on the same page.

The problem I'm facing is, once I have verifed my email, I'm still shown the same verify email page. Can someone help me.

This is my login page : [Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVEDQ.jpg)

This is my logic for the continue button :

```
onPressed: () async {
          final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
          if (user?.isEmailVerified ?? false) {
            // user's email is verified
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              passwordsRoute,
              (route) => false,
            );
          } else {
            // user's email is NOT verified
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              verifyEmailRoute,
              (route) => false,
            );
          }
        },
```

Comment: have you checked your if condition true or false?

Comment: How should I do that ? Could you please tell me @Yashraj

Comment: Try this : remove if else and use : user?.isEmailVerified ? navigate to password code : navigate to verify email code.

Comment: I have used "user?.isEmailVerified??passwordsRoute:verifyEmailRoute;" but I'm getting an error, "Expected an idenifier".

Comment: add == true : user?.isEmailVerified == true

Comment: If you are still on the same page then it means either the user is null or the email isn't verified, because as it seems, your logic is correct and should work. Put ```print(user?.isEmailVerified);``` before the `if ()` and see what it prints?

Comment: Where should I add that @Yashraj

Comment: yes, print isEmailVerified before condition and check its return true or false?

Comment: I'm getting the value false . @Yashraj But if I go to the login page and click on login , I get logged in without the email verification view.